# Using match in R, but keeping subsequent instances

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'a'), value = c(rep(TRUE, 4), rep(FALSE, 3)))
```

and a target:

```
target <- c('b', 'a', 'd', 'c')
```

I know that if I run the following,

```
new_df <- df[match(target, df$name), ]
```

it will return `df` in the order of the target, BUT only the first instance. In the sample data, I have subsequent instances of 'a' and 'b' in `df$name`. How can I preserve those? I do not care where they occur, only that they remain. The first instance of any name should be in the order of target (so 'a' must appear before 'd' or 'c'), but after that I don't care.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I can't get it in code, so I didn't display it. But I'm flexible without the output as far as the order, as long as 'b' appears before any instance of 'a', 'c', or 'd'. And 'a' appears before 'c' and 'd'. And 'd' appears before 'c'. So in this case it could be 'b,b,a,a,a,d,c' or 'b,a,d,b,a,a,c'. I don't care as long as the first instances are in the order of the target.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'a'), 
   value = c(rep(TRUE, 4), rep(FALSE, 3)))

target <- c('b', 'a', 'd', 'c')

> df[unlist(sapply(target, function(e) which(df$name == e))),]
```

Result:

```
  name value
2    b  TRUE
6    b FALSE
1    a  TRUE
5    a FALSE
7    a FALSE
4    d  TRUE
3    c  TRUE
```

Comment: fantastic! I had come up with something but this is much nicer. Thanks!